# how to directly invoke describe() function - jasmine/protractor tests

Tags: jasmine, protractor

take a look at this simple protractor test in the file `example.js`:

```
describe('this is my first test',function(){
    var ptor;
    it('step 1 ',function(){
        ptor = protractor.getInstance();
        ptor.get('#/');
    },30000);
});
```

in order to run this test with protractor i have to create a configuration file (`my_conf.js`) and add `example.js` to the `spec`. then from command line i'll invoke: `protractor my_conf.js`.
instead, i would like to run the test like this:
`node example.js`
so my question is, what modules do i have to require in my `example.js` test and how do i invoke `describe` and `it` functions? (you can ignore the `protractor` instance that will undefined)

thanks

Comment: Why do you want to run it this way? You could do it yourself, but it would involve a lot of copying of code that exists in protractor/lib/runner.js, and you'd need to know how you want to connect to the selenium server.

Answer (score 1):

that's probably not gonn work, I am going to guess that protractor.js is a must required, but other than that there must be a reason for protractor to run only on selenium server, where I think the protractor js will be able to mock and click the pages and behave as a virtual qa.